# Condition based on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show "Complete it" if the value of pro_percent is less than 75.

```
    <progressbar class="progress-striped active" max="100" value="user.pro_percent" type="success">
            {{user.pro_percent | number:0 }}
    </progressbar>
    <span ng-show="user.pro_percent < 75">Complete it</span>
```

I can't get my head around to write the condition for ng-show. How should I go about here?

EDIT:

I added this functionality as suggested and got the following result.

```
    <div class="progress-striped active progress ng-isolate-scope" max="100" value="user.pro_percent" type="success">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" ng-class="type &amp;&amp; 'progress-bar-' + type" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="73.33" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{width: (percent < 100 ? percent : 100) + '%'}" aria-valuetext="73%" ng-transclude="" style="width: 73.33%;">
        <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            73%
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <small ng-show="user.pro_percent < 75" class="ng-hide">Complete it</small>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if user.pro_percent is a number then this should do it:

```
<span ng-show="user.pro_percent < 75">Complete it</span>
```

Comment: Please check the edited question with the output as per your suggestion. I'm wondering if the problem is because the value is in decimal?

Comment: It seems that user.pro_percent is a string (73%). You can store it as a number, and add the percent in the view. Do you need the % sign for the progress bar?

Comment: The data that comes from the backend is 73.33 without the %. I added it just for the progress bar. Can't we do this to a string and not a number?

Comment: Okay. I got it working, finally. Thank You so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should  work just fine

```
<span ng-show="user.pro_percent < 75">Complete it</span>
```

Comment: Please check the edited question with the output as per your suggestion.

Comment: What do you see in your browser?

Comment: Nothing. It's taken over by class="ng-hide" although it is suppose to show as the pro_profile is less than 75. Value now is 73.33 as shown in the output.

Comment: Your value(73.33) is probably a string which is why it can't be compared with 75( a number). You need to convert 73.33 to a float value first(you can use parseFloat) and then compare it with 75.0

Comment: isn't there anything we can do from the frontend?! The value comes as 73.33 from the database. Nothing I can do there.

Comment: parseFloat is a javascript function so you can use it in your frontend. You could maybe use it inside your controller function.

Comment: i can't figure out how to go about using parseFloat here. Thank you though.